# CakePHP console -app error

Tags: shell, cakephp, console, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have upgraded a CakePHP 1.2 site to 2.x.

This site uses one core for multiple apps. Everything works fine, except the Shells.

I am not able to run one of the existing shells from the console.

When i try to change the app with `cake -app store` i get the following error:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class ShellDispatcher in C:\www\domains\cakes\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php on line 24

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class ShellDispatcher in C:\www\domains\cakes\lib\Cake\Console\ShellDispatcher.php on line 24
```

I am executing following commands:

`> cd C:\www\domains\cakes\store`

`> Console\cake -app store`

I get the same result on Linux(debian) environment.
Is there something wrong with the configuration or is it a bug in cake?

Comment: try to run the shell from inside the app folder (no need to set -app then!)

Comment: store is the app folder.
When executing without -app, the app will be app (while app isnt even in the structure) even if i am already in store

Comment: well, maybe it just says "app" (as a general name) - but means the real store folder. I ususally dont use the app version, but the cake one: "/store/>../lib/Cake/Console/cake"

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
Thats what i thought also, but then it says that the given Shell name does not exist. It is not that i can not change the app to store only, but i am also not able to change the app to one of the other apps (reseller/host/etc)

Comment: for the other apps you need to nagivate into those other app folders and do the same thing as I just did. then everything works smoothly and perfekt :) what shell name did you try? "cake" should give you a list of all avaiable ones.

Comment: Okay so actually you are saying that cake does not recognize my shells/tasks?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17880/discussion-between-user1581951-and-mark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thank you all for trying to solve this issue.

I have found the cause. I am using one database&core.php file for all apps, and the shell doesnt like the way how i included those files. After changing this, the errors disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove any Environment paths linked to the old cake 1.3 core?
Not that those interfere with your 2.x core. You don't need them anyway. Only the PHP one.

My guess, if you don't find any shells: you did not read the migration guides as you should have:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

the shells are now in /Console/Command/

use one of the available upgrade shells to automatically make that happen or manually change it.

PS: there are also a few changes in the way shells work that will not make 1.3 ones work out of the box in 2.x. You will have to manually resolve those issues.